# How can a linker determine the address of certain data in the .rodata section?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linker, elf

So the test platform is on Linux 32 bit.

I use gcc to generate a obj file of quickSort in this way:

gcc -S quickSort.c

and the generated quickSort.o is a relocatable ELF:

#file quickSort.o
   quickSort.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

I then use objdump to disassemble it :

```
objdump -d quickSort.o
```

and looking into the asm file generated, I am confused with this:

```
51:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
56:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
59:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   5a <main+0x5a>
5e:   c7 44 24 3c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x3c(%esp)
```

The above code is call printf function and print out a string, and if I compile quicksort.c into quicksort.s, it should like this:

```
   movl    $.LC0, %eax
   movl    %eax, (%esp)
   call    printf
```

So by looking at the relocation table, I can easily find out the relation between "5a" and printf, and I am sure linker can use this way to relocate printf and substitute "fc ff ff ff" into the real address of printf,

But I am confused with how the address of .LC0 (which is a string in the .rodata section) be relocated? I cannot find any clue in the relation table (I got the relocation table using **readelf -r quickSort.o**)

Could anyone give me some help about how the linker will find the real memory address of some data in the .rodata section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done in the same way. You should be seeing a relocation entry against `.rodata`, where `.rodata` means the start address of the part of `.rodata` that's in the current object file.

Note that `objdump -dr` might be a better tool for the job.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I think I know where is the problem now